# Função que retorna função em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções

Comecei a estudar JavaScript a pouco tempo e me deparei com uma situação em um código (exercício) que não consigo entender.

```
function hi(a,b) {
   return a*b;
}

function hello(a,b) {
   return hi(a,b+1);
}

hello(3,3);
```

O que eu entendo do código acima é:

- Passo 1: a função `hello` é chamada com os parâmetros 3,3.
- Passo 2: a função `hello` returna a função `hi` com os parâmetros *3,3*, porem a função `hi` retorna *a*b*, logo *3* * *3* = *9* certo?

Ao solicitar o `return` dentro da função `hello` o que eu imagino que aconteça é:

```
return hi(9+1);
```

O resultado seria *10*, mas ao executar o código ele me mostra o valor *12*, por que?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade este código executa nesta ordem:

- Chama `hello(3,3)`
- Dentro de `hello` **executa `b+1`** resultando em 4
- Chama `hi(3, 4)`, os valores de `a` e `b+1`
- Dentro de `hi` multiplica e retorna `a` e `b` (resultado 12)
- De volta ao `hello` o retorno de `hi`, que é 12, é retornado

O que você não tinha entendido é que a adição é feita antes de passar como argumento. Os argumentos são expressões que devem ser resolvidas antes de serem enviadas.

Em tese o valor de `a` também seria calculado antes de enviar como argumento, porém ele é uma expressão simples que não precisa fazer cálculos, então ele é usado como está.

É interessante entender essa questão de expressões para saber o que pode usar onde e o que será feito quando usa uma expressão. Por não entender que um local do programa aceita expressões de uma forma geral os programadores iniciantes costumam abusar de criação de variável. Quantas vezes vejo programas que fazem uma expressão, guardam em uma variável e depois usa a variável em apenas um lugar do programa. Isto é feito porque o programador aprendeu que um lugar aceita variáveis e ele não percebe que no lugar da variável ele poderia colocar a expressão direta. Quando usa a expressão ela é realizada antes de ser usada. Poderíamos entender seu código desta forma:

```js
function hi(a, b) {
   return a * b;
}

function hello(a, b) {
   temp = b + 1;
   return hi(a, temp);
}

hello(3, 3);
```

Variáveis são armazenamentos, elas só são necessárias quando você precisa guardar um valor. E só precisa guardar um valor quando você vai usar ele mais que uma vez no programa. Em alguns casos isto pode ser útil quando precisa de resultados intermediários.

Claro que eventualmente pode-se criar uma variável que será usada apenas uma vez para facilitar a legibilidade. Mas isto preciso ser feito com consciência, não porque não sabe que uma expressão poderia estar sendo usada.

Curiosamente quando o programador aprende que um lugar aceita expressões, ele acha que não pode usar variáveis. Exemplo:

```
if (x == 0 && y == 1)
```

poderia muito bem ser escrito assim:

```
condicao = x == 0 && y == 1;
if (condicao)
```

Nem todos percebem isto. Não estou dizendo que em geral escrever desta forma é interessante mas pode ser útil em algum ponto específico.

Como informação adicional o código não está retornando uma função, ele retorna o **retorno de uma função**. Esta distinção é importante porque de fato uma função pode retorna outra função, neste caso ela estaria retornando um algoritmo ao invés de um resultado já calculado. Mas não é o que você está fazendo.

Isto faz outras coisa e não apresenta o resultado que você desejava:

```js
function hello(a, b) {
   return function(a, b) { return a * b };
}

hello(3, 3);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ReturnFunction.js).

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Rafael é quando a função hello chama a função hi ela passa como parametro seu a e b recebidos, porem ficam a, b+1.

Tipo

```
hello(3,3) {
 //hi(3, 3+1)
 return hi(3,4);
}
```

blz

Answer (score 4):

> A função `hello` returna função `hi` com os parâmetros *3,3* porem a função `hi` retorna *a* * *b*, logo *3* * *3* = *9* certo?

Não. O que é passado para a função `hi` é *3* e *3* + *1*.

> Ao solicitar o `return` dentro da função `hello` o que eu imagino que aconteça é: `return hi(9+1)`. O resultado seria *10*, mas ao executar o código ele me mostra o valor *12* porque?

O resultado é *12* porque a função `hello` retorna o resultado da multiplicação de `a` e `b`, sendo `a` = *3* e `b` = *3 + 1*, a função `hi` multiplica *3* pelo resultado da soma entre *3 + 1*, então *3* * *4* = *12*.

Para dar o resultado que você quer, a adição tem que ser feita depois da multiplicação.

```js
function hi(a,b) {
   return a * b;
}
function hello(a,b) {
   return hi(a, b) + 1;
}

alert(hello(3,3)); // 10
```