# Por que um método anônimo não pode ser atribuído a um var ou dynamic?

Tags: c#, função-anônima, inferência

O seguinte código:

```
var mostra = delegate(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
};
mostra("teste");
```

O .Net não deveria identificar o `var` como um `Action<string>`?

E o mesmo pro `dynamic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta para isso, que você se pergunte qual seria o tipo do `var` então?

No caso do seu exemplo:

```
var mostra = delegate(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
};
mostra("teste");
```

`mostra` seria um delegate de que tipo? `Action<string>`? Ou seria de um outro tipo qualquer... por exemplo, eu poderia inventar um tipo de delagate qualquer:

```
delegate void Xpto(string str);
```

E agora?

Não tem como saber, pois delegates são objetos que possuem tipo no .Net.

### Como fazer então

Existem algumas maneiras para que você indique o tipo do delegate ao C#:

```
var mostra = (Action<string>)delegate(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
};
mostra("teste");
```

Ou então:

```
Action<string> mostra = delegate(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
};
mostra("teste");
```

Ou então:

```
var mostra = (Action<string>)(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
mostra("teste");
```

Sendo esta última uma alternativa do meu primeiro exemplo, só que usando uma lambda para gerar o delegate.

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do Miguel Angelo já responde bem a questão. Vou apenas colocar algumas informações que podem ajudar achar alguma outra solução em alguns casos. Claro que para a questão, a solução mais simples e óbvia é a segunda alternativa da resposta dele.

O `var` não é solução mágica e que deve ser usada sempre, é apenas um facilitador e quando não é possível usá-lo basta fazer como se fazia antes que é usar o tipo explicitamente. Não gosto das soluções de *cast*, apesar delas funcionarem. Ela só seria útil no caso do `dynamic` já que este comando "esconde" o tipo em tempo de compilação.

Note que esse é um problema tão difícil de resolver que mesmo em *runtime* não é possível identificar sem ambiguidades qual é o tipo correto, por isto o `dynamic` também não resolve.

## Por que é difícil inferir neste caso?

O Eric Lippert, o criador desta funcionalidade no compilador, já explicou em sua [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4966409/221800) porque inferir o tipo do `delegate` seria muito complicado ou mesmo impossível.

## Abuso de uso de variável

Uma coisa que deve-se pensar é se precisa de uma variável neste caso. Uma coisa que eu percebo ser muito comum é programadores acharem que variável é algo absolutamente necessário em um programa. E não é. [Variável é só um padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101) (*design pattern*).

Claro que o código ficaria ilegível mas é possível programar sem o uso de variáveis. E pasmem, respeitando o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Não estou pregando isto mas assim como falo que [exceções estão sendo abusadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20874/101) digo que programadores vivem abusando de variáveis. Provavelmente porque eles não entendem que variável é só um local para guardar um dado temporariamente. Não entendem que se não há vantagem em guardar este dado, não deveria guardá-lo.

Curiosamente por não entender isto, cometem o erro ao contrário também. Quando variáveis podem ser usadas, acabam não usando. Falo disto [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44742/101) e [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54409/101) resposta. As pessoas não entendem que expressões podem ser substituídas por variáveis, então onde ela sabe que precisa de uma expressão, ela se vê obrigada a criar uma expressão quando uma variável basta. Não canso de ver esta aberração:

```
if (booleanoQualquer == true)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Unneeded.cs).

Claro que a variável pode ser usada como forma de documentação dos passos que estão sendo feitos mas não é sua função principal, é um efeito colateral.

## Conclusão

Então é bom saber que o problema realmente é com o `var` e não com a inferência em si. É possível inferir quando há informação suficiente para inferir. Se não estivesse no `var` e sim em um lugar onde se espera uma expressão de um tipo específico, o compilador consegue descobrir se eles são compatíveis. Isto é bem mostrado [nesse blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160104222232/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2008/09/23/delegate-type-inference-in-c.aspx). Veja o [código dele executando](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SHYnLI).

Se não tiver que usar uma variável de fato, não a use e ganhe a inferência na maioria dos casos.

Não digo que você abusou porque sei que foi só um exemplo auto-contido.

Comment: Só discordo do ponto que diz *"variável é apenas um lugar para guardar um valor"*, pois como a variável possui um nome, o seu uso pode ser também o de documentar, e além disso ela também pode ser usada como uma unidade de organização. Exemplo: um cálculo complexo dividido em várias etapas (mesmo que cada etapa seja usada apenas uma vez)... do resto concordo com tudo, principalmente no que diz respeito ao abuso de variáveis, o que ocorre principalmente com os desenvolvedores menos experientes. Já vi alguns códigos em que cada linha é uma nova variável. Então é +1.

Comment: Então você não discorda porque eu falo que sem ela o código seria ilegível. É claro que eu uso bastante variáveis, até mesmo apenas para documentar. Falo com mais detalhes nos *links* que eu mostrei. E em outras respostas eu falo como código legível e melhor que código comentado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101. O que é importante é que as pessoas precisam entender a função de cada coisa em um código, elas programam mas não entendem a estrutura de um código, aí sequer podem usar sua criatividade. Tem que saber pq por açúcar no molho de tomate, senão não tem como fazer macarrão gostoso.

Comment: Exatamente! Eu só discordei daquela frase específica... mais especificamente da palavra *apenas*. Seu bom senso é notável, então eu também não vou ficar discordando de muitas coisas... =).

Comment: Gostei da analogia que fez com temperos. Assim como o uso de temperos deve ser equilibrado na culinária, o uso dos recursos da linguagem deve ser equilibrado na programação. Tanto a falta como o exagero produzem resultados não tão apreciáveis. É ai que entra o "bom senso" do "cheff"... ele deve conhecer o freguês, sua cultura, seus desejos. O desenvolvedor também, sabendo que seus clientes são sua empresa, seus usuários, e também seus amigos desenvolvedores, e até ele mesmo num momento futuro.

Comment: O "apenas" foi mais no sentido do que se faz com a variável. A documentação é efeito colateral e o único jeito de documentar sem armazenar o valor é com comentário. Mas pode discordar, eu sei falar besteira e quero saber quando é o caso :) O comentário pega um outro viés do que eu falei. Tem que saber para que serve cada tempero, causas e consequências de usá-lo em conjunto com os outros e saber o que vai produzir algo desejável.